# GPO Redirected My Documents not displayed in Libraries (Server 2012 & Win 7)

Tags: windows-server-2012, folder-redirection

New build Server 2012 & windows 7 desktops.

Windows 7 library's are not reflecting the folder redirection set by the GPO, although the redirection is working.

We use GPO's to redirect the users "My Documents" to their Home folder on the network

When I do this by GPO, the Documents entry under Libraries, still points to the (now) empty one on the local disk in the user's profile. C:\users\default\Documents

However the 'My Documents' folder shows up in the users networked Home folder. Eventvwr shows that folder redirection is working successfully.

The folder is indeed being redirected, but not visible under Libraries.

When I open the personal folder for the user we see two My Document folders, one is the redirected one and one is the default my documents folder (the one showing in libraries)

I must be doing something wrong. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Libraries can only show *indexed* locations. If the redirected location isn't indexed, it won't appear under a library. Usually this will throw up a beige bar at the top of the library folder that says something to the effect of "unsupported locations". We had this problem a while back in my environment. If you would like the complete solution, leave me a comment and I'll write it up.